# Android parse.com check duplicate Object

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am beginner in Parse.com android sdk. I successfully saved some Object in Parse server

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Save done");
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "ex" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

When I show my Parse Dashboard in my GameScore 'Table' has same values (table contains duplicate values, but objectID is different).

[image]

I have a question: is this correct or must I remove duplicate values in my 'GameScore's object?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the object to parse multiple times...as in you ran the code in the snippet in you question multiple times, you should be seeing the same information multiple times with different objectIds. If you made the call only once and it shows up multiple times, there may be a problem. There is, however, no problem with having the same values for multiple objectIds. You shouldn't have multiple rows with the same objectId, though.